# Split a column in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get all records where I have a column concatenated with a `:`.

```
SELECT serName FROM tblService WHERE serBqtID=1;
```

The data stored in table as like this:

```
serName             serStatus
-------             ---------
catering            Available
Stage               Available
Projector           Available
Segreg:extra        Available
DJ:extra            Available
```

I want to get below results by removing `:extra` from column in query:

```
serName             serStatus
-------             ---------
Segreg              Available
DJ                  Available
```

I'm not sure what should I do with my above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server, you would do:

```
select left(t.serName, charindex(':', t.serName + ':') - 1) as serName, . . .
from tblService  t
where t.serBqtID = 1 and t.serName like '%:%';
```

You can find the columns using:

```
select t.*
from tblService t
where t.serBqtID = 1 and t.serName like '%:%';
```

The original tag on the question was MySQL, where you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(t.serName, ':', 1) as serName, . . .
from tblService  t
where t.serBqtID = 1 and t.serName like '%:%';
```

Answer (score 0):

For MS-SQL use:

```
select substring(t.serName,0,charindex(':',t.serName)) as serName, . . .
from tblService  t
where t.serBqtID = 1 and t.serName like '%:%';
```